# Webservice response time After Idle Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a webservice which returns the content of a pdf.

I've noticed that when I've left the website for a while and I call the method of the service it takes a long time to respond. Any subsequent calls take less than a second which is great.

Can someone tell me why this is? Has the service gone to sleep and needs to reinitialise?

What would be a good way around this? Is there something I could do each time that page gets visited to tell the service a request could come through very soon?

Comment: I presume you're using old ASMX web services and not WCF?

Comment: Yes, it's someone elses web service which is an asmx web service. Does that make a difference?

Comment: it makes a huge difference. It's a totally different runtime environment. In this case, your solution lies with IIS, but a WCF service could have been self-hosted, or hosted in WAS (Windows Process Activation Service), in which case, IIS settings would not have helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're hosting the service in IIS.

Like any other web-based application, the AppDomain in which the service runs can be recycled for several reasons. One possible reason is an idle timeout.

If you don't want it to time out due to idleness, you can change the IIS settings appropriately.

Comment: Yes it's hosted in IIS. Thanks for your suggestion!